# Remix compile error: Expected primary expression

Tags: solidity, remix

```
function Renting() public {

    checkUser[owner] = true;
    struct govt = Person(owner, 'Owner', 'Owner', 0, 'None',  new uint[](0), new uint[](0));

    addressToPerson[owner] = govt;
}
```

When I try to compile my contract I get an error saying Expected primary expression: `struct govt = Person(owner, 'Owner', 'Owner', 0, 'None',  new uint[](0), new uint[](0));`

I referred once to Person in my contract

```
struct Person {

    address eth;
    string legalName;
    string email;
    uint aadhaar;

    string signTerms; 

    uint[] myOwned;
    uint[] myRented;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.5.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this declaration for person:

`Person memory govt = Person(owner, 'Owner', 'Owner', 0, 'None', new uint[](0), new uint[](0));`

I'd recommend reading a little more about [arrays in Solidity.](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.12/types.html#arrays) You'll need to decide if you want your arrays to be `memory` or `storage`, which is very dependent on what your goals are. Since you've assigned them to size zero, please note that memory arrays cannot be resized. You'll also need to consider if you want your Person stored in memory or storage.